# How to get the parent element in an HTML string at a given offset?

Tags: javascript, dom, text, highlight, offset

### New Question

I am looking for a way in Javascript to get the parent element of a given position in an HTML string (e.g. document.innerHTML or document.body.innerHTML).

Simple example:

```
<p>I really <em>like <a href="...">stackoverflow</a></em> a lot.</p>
                                   ^...........^
                               Offset 35  to  48
```

Given offset 35 (to 48), the function should return the node object of the "a" element. I am wondering whether this is possible at all and, if it is, what would be a good approach to solve this.

*Thanks in advance for your efforts!*

---

### Old Question

Is there a way to highlight text at a given offset in an HTML document with Firefox?

I have a list of offsets and lengths of strings to highlight. I suppose I need to find out the parent element of the text node at the given offset, is this right?

I don't think it should be a problem for me to add the highlighting once I've got the right parent node, since this is simply DOM manipulation.

Do you have any ideas or hints?

**Clarification:** The offsets are relative to the contents of the body tag. Thanks @ Jonathan for pointing this out.

Thank you very much.

Comment: just to clarify, the offsets are relative to the beginning of all text in the document or relative to the parent node?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, have a look at my clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the source of [Search and Highlight With Javascript](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm), it may be give you a good place to start.

Comment: aside from the horrible abuse of font tags, it looks like a good place to start.