# Is there a non-naïve way of calculating a logical offset from a DOM offset?

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, offset

I have [highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49721966/5223757) some of the text inside my parent element by placing it in `<span>`s, and now want to work out what part of it is selected. I have retrieved the [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object, but it doesn't contain directly useful information. I want to get the offsets relative to the start of the text, but they're relative to the the text nodes *inside the highlighting `<span>`s* and don't line up with `parent.textContent`.

Given:

- A reference to the `parent` element
  This element contains nothing but inline elements (specifically, `<span>`s) and text nodes, but they are arbitrarily nested.
- [`Selection.anchorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode) / [`Selection.focusNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode)
  This is a reference to the text node that contains the fragment of text containing the offset position.
- [`Selection.anchorOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorOffset) / [`Selection.focusOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusOffset)
  This is a non-negative integer, where `0` is before the first character.

is there a way more efficient than the naïve "explore the tree with a cumulative count" technique to pretend that the `<span>`s don't exist for the sake of measuring the `Selection` focus and anchor points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it is any more efficient in terms of performance, you would have to measure that. In terms of lines of code the [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) should make things fairly easy. Construct range from the start of the parent element to the start of the selection and then count the characters contained in it.

A `Selection` is mostly a collection of ranges after all.

Comment: ... There it is! I knew somebody would find a clever way of doing this! Thank you.